# Why does a local var reference cause a large performance degradation?

Tags: c#, performance

Consider the following simple program:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      const int size = 10000000;
      var array = new string[size];

      var str = new string('a', 100);
      var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         var str2 = new string('a', 100);
         //array[i] = str2; // This is slow
         array[i] = str; // This is fast
      }
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("Took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.");
   }
}
```

If I run this, it's relatively fast.  If I uncomment the "slow" line and comment-out the "fast" line, it's more than 5x slower.  Note that in both situations it initializes the string "str2" inside the loop.  This is not optimized away in either case (this can be verified by looking at the IL or disassembly).

The code would seem to be doing about the same amount of work in either case.  It needs to allocate/initialize a string, and then assign a reference to an array location.  The only difference is whether that reference is the local var "str" or "str2".

Why does it make such a large performance difference assigning the reference to "str" vs. "str2"?

If we look at the disassembly, there is a difference:

```
(fast)
     var str2 = new string('a', 100);
0000008e  mov         r8d,64h 
00000094  mov         dx,61h 
00000098  xor         ecx,ecx 
0000009a  call        000000005E393928 
0000009f  mov         qword ptr [rsp+58h],rax 
000000a4  nop

(slow)
     var str2 = new string('a', 100);
00000085  mov         r8d,64h 
0000008b  mov         dx,61h 
0000008f  xor         ecx,ecx 
00000091  call        000000005E383838 
00000096  mov         qword ptr [rsp+58h],rax 
0000009b  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+58h] 
000000a0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rax
```

The "slow" version has two additional "mov" operations where the "fast" version just has a "nop".

Can anyone explain what's happening here?  It's difficult to see how two extra mov operations can cause a >5x slowdown, especially since I would expect the vast bulk of the time should be spend in the string initialization.  Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable than I will have the right answer but my guess is that the compiler knows that str2 is never used so its removes that assignment.

Comment: Check out the difference in memory usage between the two different answers. Your "slow" version is creating a brand new string and assigning it in each loop, the "fast" version is just assigning the same string over and over.

Comment: Do something with `str2` like `string str3 = str2;` and compare fast and slow.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in the fast version, you are only allocating one string and then assigning a reference to that string 10 million times, but in the slow version, you are actually allocating 10 million different strings.  Why wouldn't that be slower?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway In both situations it's allocating 10 million different strings.  In the fast version I happen to not use the result of that allocation, but it still occurs - it's not  (and can't/shouldn't) be optimized away.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You're right that the code does about the same amount of work in either case.

But the garbage collector ends up doing very different things in the two cases.

In the `str` version, at most two string instances are alive at a given time. This means (almost) all new objects in generation 0 die, nothing needs to be promoted to generation 1. Since generation 1 isn't growing at all, the GC has no reason to attempt expensive "full collections".

In the `str2` version, all the new string instances are alive. Objects get promoted to higher generations (which may involve moving them in memory). Also, since the higher generations are now growing, the GC will occasionally try run full collections.

Note that the .NET GC tends to take time linear to the number of live objects: live objects needs to be traversed and moved out of the way, while dead objects doesn't cost anything at all (they simply get overwritten the next time memory is allocated).

This means `str` is the best-case for garbage collector performance; while `str2` is the worst-case.

Take a look at the [GC performance counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your program, I suspect you'll see very different results between the programs.

Comment: The only correct answer.  The gen #0 collections in the fast version are very cheap and prevent memory usage from ballooning.  The jitter optimizer cannot otherwise prevent the needless string instances from being created, it cannot see the side-effects since the code lives in the CLR.

Comment: Will someone please compare with `array[i] = string.Intern(str2);`?

Comment: Totally wrong. "the code does about the same amount of work in either case" - NO, it does not. They are as far away as they can be with that trivial loop and totally do not the same. Which is where the performance difference comes from.

Comment: @TomTom Both loops include the var `str2 = new string('a', 100);` line - there is no difference in allocation between the two versions.

Comment: @Jack The sad thing is that the JIT is apparently really not clever enough to optimize the unnecessary string constructor away. That's really disappointing considering how simple this scenario is :( With a good compiler there *should* be a noticeable difference in performance.

Comment: @Voo I don't think it's possible (or advisable) to optimize-away calls to most methods (including constructors).  There's no way of knowing what side effects and code are run in that method.  It must also evaluate all the arguments to the call since they might be calls to other methods or mutate state - e.g. new string ('a', GetSomeValue()) or new string('a', i++).  The compiler doesn't know whether methods are "const" or what happens inside them.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks - this is the correct answer.  I looked at the performance counters including Gen 0 promoted Bytes/sec and promoted memory from Gen 0 to Gen 1.  These indeed spike considerably during the "slow" version.  The % Time in GC is also much larger, although that's more difficult to interpret since it's the total across all cores, so it doesn't look like a lot, but it's probably almost all the time for the single core that's running this program.  Thanks for your valuable insight.

Comment: @JonB The JIT knows exactly what the string constructor does since it has access to the code by definition. If it didn't there would have been a loader exception before we even got that far.

Comment: Yes, but you do know the JIT is not exactly smart, particularly not in the newer versions? It is FAST - but it misses the more optimizing pass that java does. They got rid of a lot of optimizations in the 4.6 update for the new jit.

Comment: Another point should be memory allocation: Version 2 will have increasing memory consumption to keep all those strings in memory, and may have to allocate new memory-pages from the system, which is a slow system-call... Version 1 will most likely always reuse the same memory location, maybe even have it in the processor cache and not even do a real memory write to RAM

Comment: Still confused with "In str version, at most two string instances are alive at a given time" and "In the str2 version, all the new string instances are alive.". I've just opposite thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

No, a local reference is not slow.

What is slow, is creating tons of new string instances, which are classes. While the fast version reuses the same instance. This also can be optimized away, while the constructor call can not.

Comment: Yes, but in both cases the ton of new string instances are created.  Nothing is optimized away, which can be verified by looking at the IL and assembly.  So that doesn't explain the performance issue.

Comment: String instances are not classes.

Comment: Can you confirm that the string construction is optimized away in the IL?

Comment: Why should I? I can confirm the string construction is NOT optimized away. It can not be. You can confirm it. Use a memory profiler.

Comment: Then your answer doesn't make sense. If the second string construction (inside the loop) can't be optimized away in the fast version, then they're both constructing the same strings. Since they would both do the same amount of work constructing strings, then expensive string construction can't be the reason for the performance difference. (In other words, JonB's comment on your answer is correct.)